# ContextConfiguration RunWith WebAppConfiguration annotations together

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc

I have class which annotated these annotations:

```
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:pathToXml.xml" })
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
```

Can you explain what features I had after I added these annotation on my class ?

Answer (score 3):

You'll get the features described in `@WebAppConfiguration` configuration javadoc.

`WebApplicationContext` mostly changes the way resources are loaded, i.e. resources with unspecifed resource prefix will be loaded from `src/main/webapp` or from the location in `value` parameter(they won't be available in Spring context otherwise, because usually webapp folder is not included to classpath) instead of `classpath:`.

Also you will be able to to test the code which uses other WebApplicationContext features- [ServletContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html) beans, Session and Request bean scopes etc.

That means that you will be able to use [Spring MVC Test Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework)

Answer (score 0):

So, battling with the need to read database creation scripts for the in-memory database from `src/test/resources` in tests annotated with `@WebAppConfiguration`, I noticed that in the mock application context created, the `resourceLoader` field was null. So, I created a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer` that sets this field to an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` instance.

Then all tests that need access to the regular resources just add something like `@ContextConfiguration(initializers = { MyConfigurableContext.class })`

Seems to do the trick, but obviously YMMV